# Calculating Yaw/pitch and taking 180/-180 flips into account?

Tags: java, rotation, logic, trigonometry, minecraft-forge

I am trying to create a worm like entity in Minecraft. it is extremely long so it needed to be broken up into multiple parts

Each part follows the previous so 9>8>7>6>5>4>3>2>1>0

0 being the head of the worm

Each part uses trig in order to find where to place / rotate itself based on the position and rotation of the part it is following

```
    public void pseudoChild(Entity parent, float length, Entity child) {

    float parentYaw = (parent.rotationYaw + 90) * 0.0174533F;
    float parentPitch = (parent.rotationPitch) * 0.0174533F;

    double x = ((length * MathHelper.cos(parentPitch) * MathHelper.cos(parentYaw)) + parent.posX);
    double y = ((length * MathHelper.sin(parentPitch)) + parent.posY);
    double z = (length * MathHelper.cos(parentPitch) * MathHelper.sin(parentYaw)) + parent.posZ;

    float yaw = child.rotationYaw + ((parent.rotationYaw - child.rotationYaw) * 0.1F);
    float pitch = child.rotationPitch + ((parent.rotationPitch - child.rotationPitch) * 0.1F);

    child.setLocationAndAngles(x, y, z, yaw, pitch);
}
```

the problem that I am having is when the head rotates to or from 180/-180 it flips to one or the other. I printed out the yaw in the log to show what happens

```
181.59375
182.59375
183.59375
184.59375
-174.78125
-173.78125
-172.78125
-171.78125
```

This causes the body segments to briefly rotate 360 degrees from positive to negative or vise versa depending on the rotation direction.

A vid of the phenomenon
https://youtu.be/8PYXfl3101k

I am not sure how to solve this issue without using my own custom floats for pitch and yaw and forgo using the minecraft variables as they flip suddenly at 180/-180

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you setting yaw and pitch on a Model? or on entities?

Comment: On the entity which the model then uses to rotate.

I ended up just making my own pitch and yaw variables that don't roll over, so problem solved I guess.

Comment: How does that perform on client <-> server enviroment. Since your own variables are most likely not synced via datawatcher

Comment: It didn't perform well at all :P. Even with datawatchers syncing the data to teh client, and the client picking up the interim, thre was a lot of teliporting and stuttering.
I ended up making the body segments client side only. They render quite well now. They cannot do any damage to players but they can still affect the players velocity, so they can knock back a player that gets too close.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skvAPODzl6A

Comment: Thought so much. You can still do your original idea, but you have to segmentise more. Take a look at twilight forests naga for inspiration.